# working with Mongo Db & MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb

I recently starting working on a project where I am using Mongo Db to interact with an MVC4 web application.

I have limited knowledge of Mongo Db so is there any resources available that come recommended in the context of .net and Mongo? Any books available that are recommended?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you start with the official C# driver from 10gen found [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center).

There are no books specific to .NET and MongoDB. As the drivers are becoming very similar (as much as possible, yet with variances for specific language/platforms), you should be able to learn from many of the samples available and other resources on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

I advice [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/273145/Using-MongoDB-with-the-Official-Csharp-Driver) and [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/04/16/nosql-with-mongodb-norm-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx), for some of my friends that articles was healpfull.

But when you want to work with mongo - [Little MongoDB book](http://openmymind.net/mongodb.pdf) is something that you must read.